# adding a watermark only to target images (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding watermarks for images. For instance: I want to display an image (pure HTML). If a user clicks on the image however, there should be a watermark, showing where that photo comes from.

I was thinking about a layer-solution. Putting an invisible layer over the main image and link to another image instead. That would force me to have every photo two times on my server. Not the best idea.

I found a lib called `watermark.js` (link here: [watermark.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/)).
However, this would only allow me to put watermarks right in the beginning.

To explain the situation: User on my site sees everything without watermark, opening it directly in the browser should add the watermark.

Another solution I had was to always apply a watermark via script, and remove it if the user is currently on my site.

Maybe you have a solution to apply watermarks only on the linked images. I'd like to realize it via `jquery`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the code that will determine if a user is "*on your site*".

Comment: Well, i havn't written it yet, obviously. But sites likes 9gag are doing this as well, so there has to be a solution for it. If I'm wrong and this is not doable, just tell me. Checking a specific regexp if the url equals something to have an indicator wheater the user is on the site, or not.

Comment: How would this work since the Client can be hacked? Not to mention you only need the URL to see your image anyways. Best to do Watermark creation Server Side.

Comment: Well, i wouldn't mind if people would fake the regexp, disable JS or something. It is really nothing too important and IF the clientside is hacked, well, still okay. It is only a missing watermark. 
You are right though, was thinking about PHP as well for adding a watermark. That would still be the same problem anyway. How to trigger only, if the target is a image-format.

Comment: In PHP the same problem would not exists since you can deny access to your images on the Server, making them only available as `src='filename.php'`. http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php